# How does this line of code work in python?

Tags: python

I am currently writing some codes. can someone explain to me what does  the line `"product.authors.append(self)"` do? I can't seem to grasp the logic.

Thanks!

```
class Software:

    def __init__(self, name, language):
        self.name = name
        self.language = language
        self.version = 0.1
        self.authors = []
        print(f"New software {self.name} v{self.version} created!")

class Programmer(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, age, gender, languages):
        super().__init__(name, age, gender)
        self.languages = languages
        self.products = []
        print(f"Programmer {self.name} has joined the ranks")

    def write_code(self, product, new=True, version=0.1):
        print(f"{self.name} is working on {product.name} v{product.version}")
        product.authors.append(self)
        if new:
            self.products.append(product)
        else:
            product.version = version
            print(f"{product.name} v{version} released!")
```

Comment: It adds `self`, the current `Programmer`, to the contributors of the `product` when they `write_code` for it.

Answer (score 0):

It adds the **Programmer** person (the current object) to the **list  of product authors**.

You can explain it, in terms of your code, as follows: If a programmer writes a code in the software, add this programmer to a list of product authors.

Answer (score 0):

Product will be an object giving information on a product, including the authors. This attribute `authors` of `Product` is a list of `Programmer` objects, since the authors are all programmers. The line `product.authors.append(self)` is adding the `self` (which is the instance of the class you're on) to the list of authors.

This means that when the `Programmer().write_code()` function is called, the person who is the programmer in question is given credit for the product they are working on.

Answer (score 0):

When a  person writes code he is added to the list of authors of the product.

From the code, I infer that product class has an "authors" data structure (list, string or set) to which the current programmer is added when the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Product is of type Software,
So product.authors refere to the list in Software.

```
def __init__(self, name, language):
        self.name = name
        self.language = language
        self.version = 0.1
        self.authors = [] #THIS ONE
        print(f"New software {self.name} v{self.version} created!")
```

append add a new element to a list.

so

```
 product.authors.append(self)
```

add a new element to the authors that belong to product

the element that is added is an object of type Programmer